# Open Windows shared folder through linux machine

Tags: python, urllib

I am using python 2.5 on Ubuntu, and there's a machine in the same network called `machine1`. The folder is shared.

How to to get a file in a specific folder of that machine?

I have tried, with no success:

```
urllib.urlopen('\\machine1\folder\file.txt')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux has a utiliy called `smbmount`, which can be found in package smbutils I believe.

This is a command line utility which mounts a Windows share to a directory on the local machine, optionally with username/password.

smbmount is I believe a utility which runs as root, so whether it's suitable for you I don't know. Maybe it can be used as user.

You could either mount the share by default on the Linux machine, thereby accessing the files on it as local files, or you could do the smbmount / smbumount from within the python script with exec or something like that.

```
mkdir WindowsShare # Do this only once
smbmount \\server\share /home/me/WindowsShare -ousername=...,password=...
ls /home/me/WindowsShare
smbumount /home/me/WindowsShare
```

Username and password can be written in a file for some security. Check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/smbmount).

If you need something totally python have a look at [pysmb](http://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/projects/pysmb). Terms to google for are python, smb, CIFS.

Comment: Thanks, I had this solution at hand. But I want to use it in last case. But thanks anyway. In the last case, I'll install a web service on windows (IIS). :(

Comment: There's also http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySmbClient which uses `smbclient` underneath (unlike pysmb which tries to re-implement SMB/CIFS).

Answer (score 2):

`urllib` does not understand the SMB protocol. You will need to use [`gio`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/unstable/) via pygobject in order to retrieve the file.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder is shared, I think it should be mounted in ~/.gvfs. Perhaps you can simply use `open` on the path as you see it in ~/.gvfs.

Comment: **If** `gvfs-fuse-daemon` is running and **if** the share has already been mounted in the current session.  Which you could ensure, by checking that `~/.gvfs` is mounted and running `gvfs-mount`, but why not just use GIO directly?

Answer (score -1):

You should look for the default file browser.

And then you can execute the process and pass in the folder you want as an argument (smb://machine1/folder/).

For example on windows you would do:

```
execl("explorer.exe", "D:")
```

Try to look for the path to your file browser (most of the time it's Nautilus).

So:

```
execl("/bin/nautilus", "smb://.../")
```

Some info on [execl](http://www.python.org/doc/2.1.3/lib/os-process.html)

Comment: Ok, but... I think I didn't explain myself very clear. My python script is running on Ubuntu and I want just to get a file. And there's no services in this window machine.

Comment: Please update your question with the update from your part. You want to open a file in particular?